# How to fix This erroe ? import cv2 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: image-processing

After pasting CV2 Library in Spyder library folder, when it launching from Anaconda  get this error

import cv2

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import cv2

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: You can't install a Python module by 'pasting' anything, you need to install it correctly. Please try searching here or elsewhere for `opencv python`. If you got Spyder in the Anaconda distribution, use `conda` to install OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you ! Done , I solved error by pasting python module !

Answer (score 1):

If above solution doesn't work
Open cmd promt and give following cmds.....

1) **pip uninstall**
2) pip install opencv-python (if you need only main modules ) ***or***
   **pip install opencv-contrib-python** ( if you need both main and contrib modules )
3) pip install opencv-python-headless ( if you need only main modules )***or*** **pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless**( if you need both main and contrib modules  )

*....now import cv2*

Comment: This is the only answer i've found which fixes the problem. I spent 4 hours hunting through solutions, and only pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless actually works

Answer (score 0):

If the import fails on Windows, make sure you have **Visual C++ redistributable 2015** installed. If you are using older Windows version than Windows 10 and latest system updates are not installed, **Universal C Runtime** might be also required.

Windows N and KN editions do not include Media Feature Pack which is required by OpenCV. If you are using Windows N or KN edition, please install also **Windows Media Feature Pack**.

If the above does not help, check if you are using Anaconda. Old Anaconda versions have a bug which causes the error, see https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/36 for a manual fix.

If you still encounter the error after you have checked all the previous solutions, download Dependencies and open the cv2.pyd (located usually at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\cv2) file with it to debug missing DLL issues.